# Is this the correct way to permanently set the ulimit in Debian?

Tags: debian, ulimit

Manually I can set via `ulimit -n 20000` the file descriptor limit and it works fine. To have this limit for every user also after a restart of the machine, can I add

```
*                soft    nofile          20000
```

to **/etc/security/limits.conf**?

I can't try because I can't really restart the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This is one of the correct ways. Another way is setting `fs.file-max` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

But wait, no need to restart your server to checking, run `ulimit -n 20001` from the command line, logout and login back, then re-run `ulimit -n` to see what happens.

Comment: OK, that's weird. I set via ulimit -n 20000 and then it has been set. If i logout and login again it returns me 1024. the old value.

Comment: Obviously. Because it only affects your session. The default value is still 1024.

Comment: OK, thanks. I found this here. Seems to say the same, that the 1024 is hard-coded in the kernel. http://superuser.com/a/325323/87348

Comment: N.B. in some situations it is also necessary to set the hard limit, with an extra lines inside the limits file: `*                hard    nofile          20000`